# Undo allowing a website to automatically open a protocol in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, zoom-meeting

I accidently clicked the box to allow pages in chrome to open zoom without showing a prompt. Is it possible to undo this? If not, where is the file stored that contains this data? Can I remove the entry manually?

This is the check box I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find how to do this in the Chrome GUI. But:

- Close Chrome
- `notepad "%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"`
- Find `{"zoommtg":true}`
- Remove all `"https://something.zoom.us":{"zoommtg":true}`
- If needed, replace the double commas `,,` introduced by the previous operation by single commas `,` (not sure how strict Chrome's JSON interpreter is)

Voilà!

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: Zoom does NOT show up in handlers as expected.
>
> At this time, I was able to get the Zoom prompt to pop again by clearing my
> Site Data and Cookies from the last hour. This testing was the first
> time I had used Zoom, so all my records were fresh. Some further testing is
> required to isolate exactly which cookie or data is stored. Just
> removing all cookies that showed up when searching "zoom" in the Chrome Cookies
> menu did not work.
>
> [image: Clear browsing data]

From Chrome, click on *Settings*:

[image: Chrome Settings]

Then click on *Privacy and Security* and *Site Settings*. Expand the menu to show the *Additional Permissions*. Click on *Handlers*.

[image: Chrome Privacy]

You can modify the default handlers in this menu. You can see I have a couple handlers blocked. You should be able to remove Zoom from here. You can also poke around the different app and website settings within these menus to make sure it is removed for any other occurrence where Zoom might have permission.

[image: Chrome Handlers]

A lot of discussion of this issue online and the fact that changing these options are non obvious. If this doesn't work, and you get tired of troubleshooting, you can always go nuclear and send Chrome back to defaults. Backup and sync any data (bookmarks/settings) you want to keep before doing that.

[image: Nuclear option]

Comment: Zoom does not show up in the handlers screen.

Comment: Got it. I hadn't used Zoom before today. I just created an account and tested this myself. Confirmed it doesn't show up as a handler. According to my tests, Zoom or Chrome is storing this in the Site Data or Cookies for Zoom. However, removing only the Zoom cookies would not resolve the issue. I did a Clear Browsing History for the last hour of only Site Settings and Cookies, and the Zoom prompt popped up. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I gave myself the same issue. What worked for me was clearing all my browsing data from the last hour. Deleting just the cookies for Zoom was insufficient. I used ctrl-shift-del and checked all the boxes. As soon as the data was cleared, the prompt was restored.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. I removed the cookies and it worked.